# Unknown column 'form_complete' in 'field list' error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I moved a WordPress site and MySQL database from Windows to a Linux hosting. The site has multiple PHP page application sequence. When it navigates to the last page I receive this unknown column error. (This is where all the data collected is inserted into the database) This error did not occur before the move to the Linux host.

This field does not exist in any of the PHP files. This field does not exist in the database. I ran a SQL query to verify that it is not in the database.

Any ideas why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: look at the code which generates the query to find out why it adds that field

Comment: CMS may have there standard to access tables so this error  is because CMS looking for this column,Try to find code which is doing that.

Comment: The code that generates the query is in the PHP files. None of the PHP files contain "form_complete".